# Heroku Blob does not exist

Tags: postgresql, heroku

If Heroku Postgres doesn't allow blob, what should I use to store binary data?

```
2012-05-30T05:59:36+00:00 app[web.1]: [debug] c.j.b.StatementHandle - create table image_info (
2012-05-30T05:59:36+00:00 app[web.1]: id                        bigint not null,
2012-05-30T05:59:36+00:00 app[web.1]: image_id                  varchar(255),
2012-05-30T05:59:36+00:00 app[web.1]: subject_id                varchar(255),
2012-05-30T05:59:36+00:00 app[web.1]: web_thumbnail             blob,
2012-05-30T05:59:36+00:00 app[web.1]: created_date              timestamp,
2012-05-30T05:59:36+00:00 app[web.1]: image                     blob,
2012-05-30T05:59:36+00:00 app[web.1]: thumbnail                 blob,
2012-05-30T05:59:36+00:00 app[web.1]: constraint pk_image_info primary key (id))
2012-05-30T05:59:36+00:00 app[web.1]: [debug] c.j.b.PreparedStatementHandle - update play_evolutions set last_problem = 'ERROR: type "blob" does not exist
2012-05-30T05:59:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   Position: 176 [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:42704]' where id = 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [bytea](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-binary.html), blob isn't a PostgreSQL datatype.

Comment: @ChrisNicola the wiki page is a bit confusing.  Basically for Postgres "blob" refers to large object support (almost never needed) ,whereas BYTEA refers to binary data of arbitrary length, similar to MySQL's BLOB.